# Read complete HTTP request-header

Tags: java, sockets, io, http-headers

I'm currently creating a little webserver (for testing purposes) and I have a problem reading the HTTP request-header (coming from the browser, chromium in my case).

First, I simply tried something like this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")
);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while (in.ready()){
    builder.append(in.readLine());
}
return builder.toString();
```

This worked fine for the first request. However, after the first request was done, the `ready()`-method only returned `false` (i closed the `client_socket` as well as all readers/writers).

After a little searching I stumbled across this older question: [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/in-java-how-do-i-read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

I tried the first four solutions (two with Apache Commons, the one with the `Scanner` and the one with the do-while loop). All of them blocked for ever and the browser gave me a "Website not reachable"-error.

I'd like to do this on my own (without using any library's or embedded servers), that's why I even try.

I'm a little lost right now, how would you go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading from the socket until there is no more data to read.  That is wrong.  You need to keep reading until you encounter a 0-length line, then process the received headers to determine if there is more data to read (look for `Content-Length: ...` and `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` headers), eg:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
String line;
do
{
    line = in.readLine(); 
    if (line == "") break;
    builder.append(line);
}
while (true);
// use builder as needed...
// read message body data if headers say there
// is a body to read, per RFC 2616 Section 4.4...
```

Read [RFC 2616 Section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4) for more details.  Not only does this facilitate proper request reading, but doing so also allows you to support HTTP keep-alives correctly (for sending multiple requests on a single connection).

Comment: Although your given code-snipped wouldn't compile (`String` starts upper case), the fixed version works fine. I'll also check the referenced RFC, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested above by Remy Lebeau is wrong, as it was shown in a test of mine. This alternative is fail-safe:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
String line;
do
{
    line = in.readLine(); 
    if (line.equals("")) break;
    builder.append(line);
}
while (true);
```

Refer to: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)